# Using objects as a data source for a remote SQL Server Reporting Services report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Is it possible to use objects as a datasource for a remote SSRS report?   I know it is possible to use objects locally from within an application.   I would like to like to use business objects as a data source for reports that are run on the SSRS server.   In the past I have created stored procedures that returned the same information as my business objects.   This is redundant and therefore would like to find a better way.

Would it work if I expose my business objects as web services?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience this cannot be done with SSRS reports, at least not easily and sensibily. You can add custom assemblies to enhance what you can do with code expressions but I doubt you'll get much ROI on trying to bind the SSRS controls to the objects through the expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this in a less than ideal way when integrating reporting services into a larger application.  Because I needed reports run against different databases with identical schemas depending on the client database they were coming from I used a custom authentication provider to have my reporting services code deploy a new report for a client user the first time it is requested for that client.  (The rdl files are stored in my client databases and on login they are deployed and I programmatically change datasources when it is being deployed the first time for that client).

This solution worked well for my situation but it's fairly involved and probably not exactly what you're looking for.  If you can, http://www.gotreportviewer.com/ might suit your needs.